# Null pointer exception creating an intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to create an intent to a new activity on an application but a null pointer exception is thrown when the activity is created, which forces the emulator to close. Any ideas?

```
    ...
    ...
//connect objects with the xml view
searchbar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtxt);
btmsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbtm);
searchopt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.advsearchtxt);

searchopt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent bi = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), adv_search.class);
        startActivity(bi);
    }
});
//make the search when click on search buttom
btmsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    ...
    ...
```

The logcat of the application is the follwing:

```
02-29 19:54:42.313: D/AndroidRuntime(628): Shutting down VM
02-29 19:54:42.313: W/dalvikvm(628): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
02-29 19:54:42.313: E/AndroidRuntime(628): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.remotedata.firstapp/com.remotedata.firstapp.DataconectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.remotedata.firstapp.DataconectActivity.onCreate(DataconectActivity.java:54)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
02-29 19:54:42.323: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  ... 11 more
02-29 19:54:42.334: I/dalvikvm(628): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-29 19:54:42.334: E/dalvikvm(628): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: The stack trace indicates the error is in `onCreate()`, at line 54. Looking at that line will give you a strong clue -- or you could tell us which is line 54 in this code.

Comment: I already looked up at that so the line is startActivity(bi);
but this is  is a fire and forget intent

Comment: adv_search.class is this activity?

Comment: my guess is that getApplicationContext() is returning null.  I assume that you're not in an an Activity so that's why you're not using *this*.  Run the debugger and see what getApplicationContext() is returning.

Comment: The stacktrace says the error is in `DataconectActivity.onCreate()`. The `startActivity()` call is in `(something)$n.onClick()`, so that's *not* it; are you sure you're looking in the right file?

Comment: yes this is the main file of the app, also it works great with out searchopt.setClickOnListener(.... that is the one that generate the problem

Comment: the line 54 is the startActivity(bi);  the on clicklistener is the line 50

Comment: @thinksteep yes adv_search.class is an activity also I've added the activity to the manifest.xml

Comment: Try putting Intent bi = new Intent(YourClassName.this, adv_search.class); startActivity(bi); I too think getApplicationContext() is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you gave, there are only two lines that could produce a `NullPointerException`.

Either it because `searchopt` is null (does `R.id.searchtxt` belong to you current layout ??)
Or it is `btmsearch` that is null (does `R.id.searchbtm` belong to you current layout ??)

Comment: doh!! a noob mistake searchtxt is another textview id on the samelayout!!

Answer (score 0):

All of the following is actually one line of code:

```
searchopt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent bi = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), adv_search.class);
        startActivity(bi);
    }
});
```

Since nothing inside the braces is evaluated when that line of code is reached, if the error is on that line, it must be `searchopt` that is null. You need to re-check your layout: make sure there is really a view in that layout with the ID `advsearchtxt`, and make sure it is really an instance of `TextView`.